# jQuery $.post() using output data as selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post, selector

I am trying to build a quiz environment. The user selects an answer and then clicks submit. Upon submit, the following jquery is called:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn-large').click(function() {
        $.post("correct_quiz.php",
        {
            choices : $('input[name=choice][type=radio]:checked').serialize()
        },
        function(data) {
            var temp = '#correct' + data;
            var temp2 = '#correct3';
            $(temp).show();  // Make the wrong/right icons visible
        });
    });
});
```

This jquery makes a green or red icon appear, based on whether the answer was correct or not. The correct_quiz.php script contains:

```
<?php 
       $root = "/users/stadius/maapc/public_html/";
       include($root . "connect_to_database.php");

       $choices = $_POST['choices']; // This will for example output "choice=3"
       echo substr($choices,7,7); // This will then output "3"
?>
```

I ran into a problem, when I try the above jquery code with variable temp2 the script works like I want. But when I try it with variable temp it doesn't. When I debug, I see that they contain exactly the same string though: both are '#correct3' (when I choose the 3rd answer).

So why is this not working when I use variable temp, and is working when using temp2?

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` in the return handler and check the value which is actually being returned.

Comment: I get a multi-line string, like this:
"

3"
So, that might indeed be the problem. However, why do I get this multi-line string? Same thing when I use explode instead of substring.

Comment: Ok, it didn't show on here as a multi-line string, but in reality it is. There's an empty line in the console, and then my number.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line:

`echo substr($choices,7,7);`

Try to use:

`$list = explode('=', $choices);`

`echo $list[1];`

instead of `substr`

Comment: Hi thanks, but this didn't change anything. The explode method is what I will need when multiple answers must be correct though.